# shell - Characters contained in both strings - edited

Tags: shell, unix, dash-shell

I want to compare two string variables and print the characters that are the same for both. I'm not really sure how to do this, I was thinking of using `comm` or `diff` but I'm not really sure the right parameters to print only matching characters. also they say they take in files and these are strings. Can anyone help?

Input:

```
a=$(echo "abghrsy")
b=$(echo "cgmnorstuvz")
```

Output:

```
"grs"
```

Comment: Must the characters be in the same position?

Comment: No they can be where ever, I edited the question to reflect that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use Character Classes with GNU Grep

The isn't a widely-applicable solution, but it fits your particular use case quite well. The idea is to use the first variable as a character class to match against the second string. For example:

```
a='abghrsy'
b='cgmnorstuvz'
echo "$b" | grep --only-matching "[$a]" | xargs | tr --delete ' '
```

This produces `grs` as you expect. Note that the use of *xargs* and *tr* is simply to remove the newlines and spaces from the output; you can certainly handle this some other way if you prefer.

### Set Intersection

What you're really looking for is a set intersection, though. While you can "wing it" in the shell, you'd be better off using a language like Ruby, Python, or Perl to do this.

#### A Ruby One-Liner

If you need to integrate with an existing shell script, a simple Ruby one-liner that uses Bash variables could be called like this inside your current script:

```
a='abghrsy'
b='cgmnorstuvz'
ruby -e "puts ('$a'.split(//) & '$b'.split(//)).join"
```

#### A Ruby Script

You could certainly make things more elegant by doing the whole thing in Ruby instead.

```
string1_chars = 'abghrsy'.split //
string2_chars = 'cgmnorstuvz'.split //
intersection  = string1_chars & string2_chars
puts intersection.join
```

This certainly seems more readable and robust to me, but your mileage may vary. At least now you have some options to choose from.

Comment: The first line of code worked fantastically. That's exactly what I was hoping for the whole time\, some nice one liner that gets the job done without muddling my code.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to do that much work to assign `$a` and `$b` shell variables, you can just...

```
a=abghrsy
b=cdgmrstuvz
```

Now, there is a classic computer science problem called the [*longest common subsequence*<sup>1</sup>](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence) that is similar to yours.

However, if you just want the common characters, one way would let Ruby do the work...

```
$ ruby -e "puts ('$a'.chars.to_a & '$b'.chars.to_a).join"
```

---

<sup>1. Not to be confused with the different [*longest common substring* problem.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem)</sup>

Comment: The system I'm working on doesn't have ruby and I can't install it because I'm not the admin.

Comment: Ok, split the strings one per line, run `comm -3` and then combine the  output lines. Ugly, but it would work.

Comment: How do I use `comm` with strings because it normally wants a file. I've tried `comm -3 $a $b` `comm -3 '$a' '$b'` `comm -3 "$a" "$b"`

Comment: Well, you would have to put them in a file, yes. There are tricks with bash that can help but I would keep it simple. You can separate a string into files of one character each with `split -b 1`.  Or, could you write a C program?

Answer (score 1):

Using gnu coreutils(inspired by @DigitalRoss)..

```
a="abghrsy"
b="cgmnorstuvz"

echo "$(comm -12 <(echo "$a" | fold -w1 | sort | uniq) <(echo "$b" | fold -w1 | sort | uniq) | tr -d '\n')"
```

will print `grs`. I assumed you only want uniq characters.

**UPDATE:**
Modified for dash..

```
 #!/bin/dash

 string1=$(printf "$1" | fold -w1 | sort | uniq | tr -d '\n');
 string2=$(printf "$2" | fold -w1 | sort | uniq | tr -d '\n');

 while [ "$string1" != "" ]; do
   c1=$(printf '%s\n' "$string1" | cut -c 1-1 )
   string2=$(printf "$2" | fold -w1 | sort | uniq | tr -d '\n');
   while [ "$string2" != "" ]; do
     c2=$(printf '%s\n' "$string2" | cut -c 1-1 )
     if [ "$c1" = "$c2" ]; then
       echo "$c1\c"
     fi
     string2=$(printf '%s\n' "$string2" | cut -c 2- )
   done
   string1=$(printf '%s\n' "$string1" | cut -c 2- )
 done
 echo;
```

<sub>Note: I am just a beginner. There might be a better way of doing this.</sub>

Comment: The system I have to do this on uses dash. Both of your solutions work well on my bash system, but where this eventually needs to go it does not.

Comment: @MikeWeber- I added a version, tested on dash.

Answer (score 1):

Nice question +1.

You can use an awk trick to get this done.

```
a=abghrsy
b=cdgmrstuvz
comm -12 <(echo $a|awk -F"\0" '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) print $i}') <(echo $b|awk -F"\0" '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) print $i}')|tr -d '\n'
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
grs
```

Note use of `awk -F"\0"` that breaks input string character by character into different awk fiedls. Rest is pretty straightforward use of `comm` and `tr`.

**PS:** If you input string is not sorted then you need to pipe awk's output to sort or do sort of an array inside awk.

#### UPDATE: awk only solution (without comm):

```
echo "$a;$b" | awk -F"\0" '{scnd=0; for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {if ($i!=";") {if (!scnd) arr1[$i]=$i; else if ($i in arr1) arr2[$i]=$i} else scnd=1}} END { for (a in arr2) printf("%s", a)}'
```

This assumes semicolon doesn't appear in your string (you can use any other character if that's not the case).

#### UPDATE 2: I think simplest solution is using grep -o

(thanks to answer from @CodeGnome)

```
echo "$b" | grep -o "[$a]" | tr -d '\n'
```